How do I access a class component from another component that is not being inherited, in Tkinter Python?
How do I access a class component from another component that is not being inherited?
I am creating an application using Tkinter Python. I am using classes as frames for each component.
How do I reference one component as the same instance without creating a new component, while the classes do not inherit another?
"""
Name: John Roby
Date: 10/21/2024
Description: A password manager gui app.
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from Components.Header import Header
from Components.SavedPasswords import SavedPasswords
from Components.CreatePassword import CreatePassword


# App class inherits tkinter
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Password Manager')
        self.minsize(400, 800)
        self.maxsize(400, 800)
        # Add Components
        self.header = Header(self)
        self.savedpasswords = SavedPasswords(self)
        self.createpassword = CreatePassword(self)
       



if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
    

I am trying to reference the other component in this file.
Custom Class Components Header
"""
Description: Header.py - Custom Component Class Header.
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Custom Component Header
class Header(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack()
        # Grid Layout
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4), weight=1, uniform='a')
        # Header Widgets
        self.create_header_widgets()


    def create_header_widgets(self):
        """Creates and places widgets
        that make up Header component"""
        # Widgets
        search = ttk.Entry(self)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Search")

        # Place
        search.grid(row=0, column=2)
        button.grid(row=0, column=3)

SavedPasswords
"""
Description: SavedPasswords.py - Custom Component Class SavedPasswords.
"""

import tkinter
from tkinter import CENTER, E, W, ttk

# Custom Component Class SavedPasswords
class SavedPasswords(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack()
        # SavedPasswords Widgets
        self.password_table = ttk.Treeview(self)
        # Define Columns
        self.password_table['columns'] = ("Website", "Username", "Password")
        self.password_table.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0)
        self.password_table.column("Website", anchor=W, width=120)
        self.password_table.column("Username", anchor=CENTER, width=120)
        self.password_table.column("Password", anchor=E, width=120)
        # Create Headings
        self.password_table.heading("#0", text="")
        self.password_table.heading("Website", text="Website", anchor=W)
        self.password_table.heading("Username", text="Username", anchor=CENTER)
        self.password_table.heading("Password", text="Password", anchor=E)
        # Insert Data
        self.password_table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=0, text="", values=("Facebook.com", "johnjroby@gmail.com", "Password123"))
        
        self.password_table.pack(pady=10)

CreatePassword
"""
Description: SavedPasswords.py - Custom Component Class SavedPasswords.
"""

import tkinter
from tkinter import CENTER, E, W, ttk
from Components.SavedPasswords import SavedPasswords

# Custom Component Class CreatePassword
class CreatePassword(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack()
        # Grid Layout
        self.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight=1, uniform='a')
        
        # CreatePassword Widgets
        self.website_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Website")
        self.username_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.password_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Password")
        
        self.website_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.username_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.password_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        
        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.saveValues)
        
        # Place
        self.website_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.website_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.username_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.username_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)
        
        self.password_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.password_entry.grid(row=5, column=0)
        
        self.save_button.grid(row=5, column=1)

    def saveValues(self):
        website = self.website_entry.get()
        username = self.username_entry.get()
        password = self.password_entry.get()

        self.password_table.insert(values=(website, username, password))



What "other component in this file"? You appear to be correctly referencing 3 other types defined in other modules, and instantiating them in a sensible fashion for inclusion in your App instance. What does "one component as the same instance without creating a new component" mean?

So, I need to access the self.savedpasswords instance, but over in the CreatePassword(self) component.
Is there a way to reference the App() dot notation to select the right component or attribute?

You passed self as an argument to CreatePasswords, so it's certainly possible that self.createpassword itself has a reference to the App instance that has the desired savedpasswords attribute. This is either simple, or you have design issues that go far beyond what we can diagnose and fix based on the code you've shown.

At they very least, we would need to know more about CreatePassword (and likely SavedPasswords as well) to provide a concrete answer.

savedpasswords is a treeview table that just holds the password information.
class SavedPasswords(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack()
        # SavedPasswords Widgets
        self.password_table = ttk.Treeview(self)```

createpasswords is just form section of entry and labels
        self.website_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Website")
        self.username_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.password_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Password")
        
        self.website_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.username_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.password_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        
        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Save")```

Want to add a function the button that gathers the entry information and inserts it into the treeview.

You are passing the newly created App instances, which has a savedpasswords attribute, as an argument to CreatePassword.__init__. If you need that saved passwords attribute, save a reference to it (or the App instance itself) for later use.

I added password_table as an attribute to the CreatePassword class.
class CreatePassword(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, password_table):
        super().__init__(parent)

And satisfied it in the App() component.
# App class inherits tkinter
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Password Manager')
        # Add Components
        self.header = Header(self)
        self.savedpasswords = SavedPasswords(self)
        self.createpassword = CreatePassword(self, self.savedpasswords.password_table)

This seems to work and I am able to add the values to the table.

lol you're welcome bro. If you don't want to thank me you could at least upvote the answer I gave you.

You do this by using a reference to the other object. For example, assuming the SavedPassword object has defined self.password_table, then in the main code you would use self.savedpasswords.password_table.
If instead, you need to access a method in CreatePassword from SavedPassword, you can use a reference to the main app to gain access to the other objects.
You are passing in self as the parent attribute, so you need to save that both in SavedPassword and CreatePassword like this:
class CreatePassword():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.app = parent
        ...

class SavePassword():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.app = parent
        ...

Then, from SavePassword you can access a method in CreatePassword with something like self.app.createpassword.some_method().
This isn't unique to tkinter or even python, this is fundamentally how classes and objects work and interact.


So, I need to access the self.savedpasswords instance, but over in the CreatePassword(self) component.

Ok, I don‘t know of I got that correctly, but I think what you want is just a way to have a reference to an object of another type. In Python, objects are usually treated as references, so you can have an object “stored” at two locations at the same time.
So if you need to access the savedpasswords from a CreatePassword object, I’d recommend just storing that savedpasswords inside createpassword like this:
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # your previous code..

        self.savedpasswords = SavedPasswords(self)
        self.createpassword = CreatePassword(self)
        # save savedpasswords in createpassword
        self.createpassword.saved_pw_ref = self.savedpasswords

Then, inside CreatePassword, you can access that reference:
class CreatePassword:
    # some method that needs access to savedpasswords
    def some_method(self):
        self.saved_pw_ref.do_something()
        self.saved_pw_ref.do_something_else()
        # …

If you don’t like setting attributes from outside, you can also create a method to save the reference:
class CreatePassword:
    def set_saved_pw_ref(self, ref):
        self.saved_pw_ref = ref

and then inside App you can call
self.createpassword.set_saved_pw_ref(self.savedpasswords)

Or you can also pass savedpasswords to the constructor of CreatePassword and then store it, etc..
I think for your code this is the easiest solution, however there might be other options if you refactor the code, it also depends on what savedpasswords and createpassword need to do at the end of the day, but this solution should work for you.
Please tell me if you have any questions or if I understood something wrong.
Edit
After looking at the code you posted, I think what you need is this:
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # your previous code..

        self.savedpasswords = SavedPasswords(self)
        self.createpassword = CreatePassword(self)
        # save savedpasswords in createpassword
        self.createpassword.password_table = self.savedpasswords.password_table

So instead of passing the whole SavedPasswords object, you just pass the password_table attribute of it.

The issue is I'm not accessing the component from the main App, but a different component. So, its two different components that need to reference the single instance

@JohnRoby if I understood you correctly, you had the same misconception that I had when learning Python. In Python, variables hold references to the objects, not the objects themselves. So, if you write object_a = object_b, these two variables will refer to the same object. Try this in Python: Create a list list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then write list2 = list1. Now change something in list2, like list2.append(6), and finally print list1 and list2. You will see that both list1 and list2 will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

I'm just having a hard time keeping track of the single instance that I need to work with, which after I've placed the component already. It doesn't seem to work if i have to reference the entire App component from a separate component.

@JohnRoby okay then I think I don’t understand your issue correctly. Is my solution not working for you at all, or do you just want a simpler one?

The function, def saveValues():
needs the self.password_table only instance, from SavedPasswords.

@JohnRoby so self.password_table should refer to the savedpasswords inside the App instance?

But yes, the component instances are only in the App() Component. The widget instance is inside the savedpasswords and createpassword, components.

I'm just having a hard time keeping track of the single instance that I need to work with, which after I've placed the component already.
It doesn't seem to work if i have to reference the entire App component from a separate component.
The function, def saveValues(): needs the self.password_table only instance, from SavedPasswords.
But yes, the component instances are only in the App() Component. The widget instance is inside the savedpasswords and createpassword, components.

@JohnRoby did I got that right: self.password_table should not be a SavedPasswords object, but an attribute of a SavedPasswords object

Yea that sounds right

@JohnRoby ok but this would work the same way I explained in my answer, you just have to set self.password_table to the object you want to have

If you don’t mind you could post your full code, or at least the classes we’re talking about. Just edit your question and append it at the end, I think this would help to understand your code structure

Done. Appended my component files to the top question.

@JohnRoby I edited my answer, I can’t run your code bc I’m on my tablet currently, but I think this is what you’re looking for
